# the word "palmetier" or "palmeter"

Tags: meaning, names

looking for a definition for a word that is either spelled palmetier or palmeter.  Ever heard of it?  I have looked in the Webster's Dictionary, googled it and looked on various sites.  All it says is that it is a Proper Name.   However, no idea as to what the name means.   Found various individuals with this last name, but even on ancestry type sites, found no idea of meaning of name.  Anyone able to help with this?

Comment: Context could be helpful here. Where did you run across it?

Comment: *palmier* in French is a palm tree.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the reference for [*Palmeter*](http://www.ancestry.com/name-origin?surname=palmeter) from the *Dictionary of American Family Names* on Ancestry.com, we see:

> Probably a variant of English Parmeter (see Parmenter).

So, consulting the corresponding entry for [*Parmenter*](http://www.ancestry.com/name-origin?surname=Parmenter), we find:

> **English** (mainly Essex): **occupational name for a maker of facings and trimmings**, Middle English, Old French par(e)mentier (from parement ‘fitting’, ‘finishing’, Late Latin paramentum, a derivative of parare ‘to prepare or adorn’).

Comment: Thank you for this response, everytime I go to Ancestry.com, it doesn't give me much until I register to sign up, and I didn't care to.  However, I'd like to leave the post to see if there will be something even more clear..."Probably" isn't quite what I'm looking for.   Another spelling could be Palmatier, and yes, it looks French to me...perhaps not appropriate for an English forum!!

Answer (score 0):

It can also refer to  the meter or the measurement of the palm.  Don and Luciene Palmeter of Los Angeles CA were Friends and Luciene worked with my late Grandmother in the Beverly Hills Foreign Exchange program.

Look up her son Zack Palmeter perhaps there is a relation.

Comment: You should add a source for the first sentence.